# html - border issues

Tags: html, html-table, border

I have a nested table:

```
    <table style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; border-collapse: collapse" cellpadding="0"
           cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="height: 47%; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.35; filter: alpha(opacity=35);" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 6%; width: 40%; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.35; filter: alpha(opacity=35);" nowrap />
            <td style="height: 6%; background-color: White;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="middle" >
                            <img src="~/images/loading.gif" align="middle" />
                        </td>
                        <td valign="middle">
                            <b>Please wait... </b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 6%; width: 40%; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.35; filter: alpha(opacity=35);" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="height: 47%; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.35; filter: alpha(opacity=35);" />
        </tr>
    </table>
```

My problem is with the nested table: the border appears, even if it is set to zero.Why?

Here is how it looks:

[image]

How to get rid of the borders?

Comment: **1.** Why are you using tables? **2.** And with the same code, I cannot find the borders: [**JSBin Output**](http://jsbin.com/mukogidibi).

Comment: it is a legacy code, I would preffer to change less code instead of using divs... and it would be hard to set opacity in divs. Indeed, with the same code I can't see this either in jsfiddle, but in my browser (IE 11) appears

Comment: Can't replicate dude. Can you show us where it comes by creating a [mcve]?

Comment: In chrome I don't see these borders